# c# как дать юзеру создавать класс

Tags: c#, ооп

```
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Usb name = new Usb();// здесь ошибка как сделать чтобы юзер давал имя классам
```

есть базовый класс Storage от него наследуется  Usb, Dvd, Hdd 
есть отдельный класс User он может создавать классы Usb, Dvd, Hdd  и манипулировать с методами как это реализовать ?

Comment: Данная строка с кодом не дает никакой информации. Вы хоть что-нибудь сами сделали? Приведите хоть какой-то вменяемый код.

Comment: а зачем весь код ведь мне нужно дать произвольное имя для нового класса

Comment: Пожалуйста, не стоит вандализировать вопрос.

Comment: задавать вопросы не могу

Comment: лучше удалить вопрос, все равно сам ответил

Comment: @ost1m1ron- удаление вопроса не снимет блокировку.

Comment: и что же делать ?

Comment: не могу понять если в вопросе указан код и что в нем использовано, почему я должен указывать то что мне не надо?

Answer (score 2):

```
string name = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

Storage storage = null;
switch(name)
{
  case "usb":
    storage = new Usb();
    break;
  case "dvd":
    storage = new Dvd();
    break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: а если два раза юзер создаст usb, класс с именем storage  создан и приведет к ошибке

Comment: @ost1m1ron- Э-э-э ... это мне откуда должно быть известно?

Comment: извиняюсь что не правильно выразился

Comment: могли бы вы помочь понять как реализовать данную задумку

Comment: @ost1m1ron- Наверное, мог бы. Но пока эта задумка мне неизвестна.

Answer (score -3):

```
int countUsb = 1;
int countDvd = 1;
int countHdd = 1;

Usb[] usb = new USb[countUsb];
Dvd[] dvd = new Dvd[countDvd];
Hdd[] hdd = new Hdd[countHdd];


// если юзер создал еще один класс

usb  = Array.Resize(ref Usb[] usb, countUsb.Length + 1);


for(int i = 0; i < countUsb; i++;){
 // some code
}

// извиняюсь за то что не правильно изъяснился
```

Comment: Следующий раз, пожалуйста, формулируйте вопросы правильно.
Совет: перечитывайте что вы написали.

Comment: Кроме того, ваше решение вообще не объясняет вашего вопроса. Где тут User, создающий классы? Как он их создает? Почему вы передаете countUsb в Array.Resize()? Это вообще скомпилируется?

Comment: Вообще, судя по намерениям автора вопроса, направление правильное: использовать коллекцию для хранения нескольких элементов. Только вместо ручной возни с изменением размера массива следует использовать одну из стандартных [коллекций](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx), например, [List](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).